# ansible playbook with jinja2 loop

Tags: python, ansible, firewalld, template

I need to write a playbook using jinja2 tamplate inorder to write firewalld rule in ansible.
For that I wrote

```
---
- name: Firewalld check
  hosts: localhost
  become: yes

  tasks:
  - name: Allow ICMP traffic
    firewalld:
      rich_rule: rule family='ipv4' source address=" {{ source }} " protocol value="icmp" accept
      permanent: no
      state: enabled
```

in template and

```
---

- name: Firewalld config
  hosts: localhost
  become: yes

  vars:
    source:
       - 172.16.2.114
       - 172.16.2.115
  tasks:

  - name: Rules
    template:
      src: playtem.yml.j2
      dest: playbook.yml
```

in playbook.
The output I expected is

```
---
- name: Firewalld check
  hosts: localhost
  become: yes

  tasks:
  - name: Allow ICMP traffic
    firewalld:
      rich_rule: rule family='ipv4' source address="172.16.2.114" protocol value="icmp" accept
      permanent: no
      state: enabled
  - name: Allow ICMP traffic
    firewalld:
      rich_rule: rule family='ipv4' source address="172.16.2.115" protocol value="icmp" accept
      permanent: no
      state: enabled
```

but the outcome which came is

```
---
- name: Firewalld check
  hosts: localhost
  become: yes

  tasks:
  - name: Allow ICMP traffic
    firewalld:
      rich_rule: rule family='ipv4' source address=" [u'172.16.2.114', u'172.16.2.115'] " protocol value="icmp" accept
      permanent: no
      state: enabled
```

So could anyone help me to solve this problem please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using `loop` instead of templating out a playbook.

```
---
- name: Firewalld check
  hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  vars:
    source:
       - 172.16.2.114
       - 172.16.2.115
  tasks:
    - name: Allow ICMP traffic
      firewalld:
        rich_rule: rule family='ipv4' source address="{{ item }}" protocol value="icmp" accept
        permanent: no
        state: enabled
      loop: "{{ source }}"
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was helful. But when using many varibles and many modules in a playbook, which method will you recommend?

Comment: You should give this a good read: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html It's hard to say what works best for you - highly dependant on use case and infrastructure